# Возможно ли узнать содержимое php-файла на удаленном сервере?

Tags: php

Возможно ли узнать содержимое php-файла на удаленном сервере?

Answer (score 3):

Возможно, если на этом сервере у вас есть доступ к ФТП/SSH или стоит скриптик, исполняющий консольные команды.
При правильном взаимодействии узнать код нельзя: при попытке вызвать файл, он тупо исполнится. Исключение - квайн.